# Порождение и замещение процессов. linux, язык С

Tags: linux, c, bash

Вывести список процессов указанного пользователя
[image: Запуск кода]

2. Составить программу на языке С – перед пользователем появляется
   меню:

1 – Выполнить введенную команду

2 – Запустить на исполнение файл со сценарием (см. вариант в работе 1)

3 – Вывести список процессов указанного пользователя

4 - Выход

Для выполнения пунктов 1-3 использовать порождение дочернего процесса.
Для третьего пункта предполагается реализация посредством команд shell,
сформированных в строки аргументов функций execlp или system, но если число
команд shell велико тогда можно создать командный файл и запустить его с
помощью execlp или system.

В 3 задании ошибка не могу понять почему. Помогите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут без чашки кофе невозможно разгадать код, исходный код

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  Добавил исходный код

Comment: ps aux - выводит все команды. дальше передается на grep.  `grep -v` говорит "исключить строки которые ... `^`- символ начала строки. то есть по сити вы все исключаете. поэтому ответ будет пустой. то есть результат `ps aux|grep -v ^` вернет ничего

Comment: Почему все начинающие так любят `scanf` для таких примитивных задач (причём, частенько используют неправильно, и порождают ошибки)? Ведь есть более простые и производительные, такие как `atoi`, или `strto*`, а чисто для строк - `fgets`. А вот `scanf` - это для сложного парсинга. Например - значения через запятую и прочие синтаксические конструкции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ps aux - выводит все команды. дальше передается на grep.

`grep -v` говорит "исключить строки которые ...

^- символ начала строки.

То есть по сути вы все исключаете. поэтому ответ будет пустой. то есть результат `ps aux|grep -v ^` вернет ничего